.NET MAUI VS 2022 How to specify Android Target Version?
With MAUI/VS 2022, how does one specify an Android target version other than 34?  The dropdown in Visual Studio only presents 34.  If I manually edit the manifest, and turn off the option to "transform project properties into assembly attributes during build" I get this error:
    error XA1036: AndroidManifest.xml //uses-sdk/@android:minSdkVersion '26' does not match the 
    $(SupportedOSPlatformVersion) value '21.0' in the project file (if there is no 
    $(SupportedOSPlatformVersion) value in the project file, then a default value has been 
    assumed).
    error XA1036: Either change the value in the AndroidManifest.xml to match the 
    $(SupportedOSPlatformVersion) value, or remove the value in the AndroidManifest.xml (and add 
    a $(SupportedOSPlatformVersion) value to the project file if it doesn't already exist).
    warning XA4211: AndroidManifest.xml //uses-sdk/@android:targetSdkVersion '31' is less than 
    $(TargetFrameworkVersion) ''. Using API-34 for ACW compilation.
    4>Done building project ... -- FAILED.

I am pretty certain that I have all the necessary Android SDK's installed.  Why does the Visual Studio 2022 not display them as options?

Did you check the official document about the ?

@LiyunZhang-MSFT: Yes.  I understand <uses_sdk>  settings in the Manifest.  My question was why it's not possible to set the TargetFrameworkVersion in the 2022 Project settings.  I am only presented with "34" even though many others are installed.

@DAConsulting The project setting option is used to set the compiling TFV for the project, so you don't need to set it. You can use the <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="32" android:targetSdkVersion="34" in AndroidManifest.xml to set it, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/78733354/9644964. As for the error, please see this solution:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/android/messages/xa1036#solution

@AlexandarMay-MSFT : Thanks.  Yes.... I did this and I'm now able to target 31 rather than 34.  I honestly wish MS had NOT tried to "put a theater" on the editing of the manifest, however.  It's just messy and confusing.  Remember the engineering axiom "KISS" (Keep it Simple and Stupid). ;-)

If you want to specify Android Target Version to target 31, you can manually specify the SDK by manually adding the following code to the MAUI project's Platfroms/Android/AndroidMenifest.xaml like below. You don't need to set the SDK in the dropdown in Visual Studio which is counterintuitive
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion=" " android:targetSdkVersion="31"/>

Also, it is recommended that you publish it to Visual Studio Feedback if you have any other concerns.
